# Use Numberstring in cref call

Tags: cleveref, fmtcount, refcount

Trying to conform to what my GF wants in her thesis: she would like chapter references as "Chapter One", "Chapter Two", etc.  I found [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/288720/cross-reference-chapter-number-as-string), which looks to work, but I was hoping to use these within cleveref `\cref`/`\Cref` calls to take advantage of the hyperref integration.

So far, both

```
\Crefformat{chapter}{#2Chapter~\Numberstringnum{\getrefnumber{#1}#3}
```

and

```
\Crefformat{chapter}{#2Chapter~\mtnumberstring{#1}#3}
```

result in "Chapter Zero" references - though the hyperlinks are correct.

Edit - MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{fmtcount}
\usepackage{refcount}
\newcommand\mtnumberstring[1]{\Numberstringnum{\getrefnumber{#1}}} 

%Both attempts included:
%\Crefformat{chapter}{#2Chapter~\Numberstringnum{\getrefnumber{#1}}#3}
\Crefformat{chapter}{#2Chapter~\mtnumberstring{#1}#3}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Abstract}\label{ch:abstract}

\chapter{Intro}\label{ch:intro}

\Cref{ch:abstract}

\end{document}
```

Is there any way to accomplish this, or should I just put up no hyperlinks?

The crucial bit of the current solution is:

```
\usepackage{fmtcount}
\usepackage{refcount}
\newcommand\mtnumberstring[1]{\numberstringnum{\getrefnumber{#1}}}

\begin{document}
Chapter~\mtnumberstring{ch:label}.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Can you please expand the snippets to a full (minimal) document showing the issue?

Comment: If one is going to create cross-references to chapters using text labels ("One", "Two", etc) instead of numbers, I think that the text labels should appear in the chapter headers as well. This may be achieved by loading the `fmtcount` package and issuing the directive `\renewcommand\thechapter{\Numberstring{chapter}}`. `\Cref` and `\cref` will work just fine.

Comment: Yeah - I figured that would do it, but that messes up the ToC and chapter headings [which are not the straight book ones].

Comment: Maybe you should tell us about the chapter headers and the ToC. That's where the real problems occur (and may need to be fixed).

Comment: It's not where the real problems occur - everything works exactly as expected if renewing the chapter commands, but the words are too large and conflict with other elements.  I could change the heading sizes to avoid conflict, but that's not what I'm trying to do.  The challenge is trying to have the cross-references use a different format from the ToC/headings [and yes, I know that's bad style - not my request].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were *very* close.

In the final argument of `\Crefformat`, `#1` represent the formatted label (i.e., what `\thechapter` expands to) and not the label name.
So if you had used `\numberstringnum{#1}` instead of `\numberstringnum{\getrefnumber{#1}}` it would've worked.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{fmtcount}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\Crefformat{chapter}{#2Chapter~\Numberstringnum{#1}#3}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\chapter{Abstract}\label{ch:abstract}
\chapter{Intro}\label{ch:intro}

\Cref{ch:abstract}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

---

[image]

---

---

[image]

Comment: Nuts! I think I tried `\Numberstring`, but not `\Numberstringnum`...!  Thanks!